# command "service nova-compute start" and the errors

Tags: 12.04, nova

while following the [document to configure nova-compute](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/install-guide/install/apt/content/nova-compute.html), I got the error below.

```
Command: service nova-compute start
Message(nova-compute.log) : 
2014-03-29 17:59:53.817 2908 INFO nova.openstack.common.periodic_task [-] Skipping periodic task _periodic_update_dns because its interval is negative
2014-03-29 17:59:53.850 2908 INFO nova.virt.driver [-] Loading compute driver 'libvirt.LibvirtDriver'
2014-03-29 17:59:53.872 2908 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connected to AMQP server on controller:5672
2014-03-29 17:59:53.883 2908 INFO oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] Connected to AMQP server on controller:5672
2014-03-29 17:59:53.907 2908 AUDIT nova.service [-] Starting compute node (version 2014.1-b3)
2014-03-29 17:59:53.932 2908 WARNING nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-8d1e2376-5890-4f44-8d73-c427b0dbad30 None None] Cannot update service status on host: compute1,since it is not registered.
2014-03-29 17:59:53.933 2908 WARNING nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] URI qemu:///system does not support events: internal error: could not initialize domain event timer
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 ERROR nova.openstack.common.threadgroup [-] internal error: CPU feature `tsc-deadline' specified more than once
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/threadgroup.py", line 117, in wait
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     x.wait()
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/threadgroup.py", line 49, in wait
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     return self.thread.wait()
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 168, in wait
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     return self._exit_event.wait()
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/event.py", line 116, in wait
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     return hubs.get_hub().switch()
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 187, in switch
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     return self.greenlet.switch()
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 194, in main
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     result = function(*args, **kwargs)
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/service.py", line 480, in run_service
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     service.start()
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/service.py", line 180, in start
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     self.manager.init_host()
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 810, in init_host
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     self.driver.init_host(host=self.host)
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 630, in init_host
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     self._do_quality_warnings()
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 618, in _do_quality_warnings
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     caps = self.get_host_capabilities()
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 2813, in get_host_capabilities
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     libvirt.VIR_CONNECT_BASELINE_CPU_EXPAND_FEATURES)
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 179, in doit
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     result = proxy_call(self._autowrap, f, *args, **kwargs)
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 139, in proxy_call
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     rv = execute(f,*args,**kwargs)
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 77, in tworker
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     rv = meth(*args,**kwargs)
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 3127, in baselineCPU
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup     if ret is None: raise libvirtError ('virConnectBaselineCPU() failed', conn=self)
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup libvirtError: internal error: CPU feature `tsc-deadline' specified more than once
2014-03-29 17:59:53.945 2908 TRACE nova.openstack.common.threadgroup
```

Test Env :

- VMware Fusion
- OS-Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64-bit)

  ```
  root@compute1:/etc/nova# uname -a
  Linux compute1 3.5.0-47-generic #71~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 19 22:02:52 UTC 2014 x86_64     
  x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

  root@compute1:/etc/nova# kvm-ok
  INFO: /dev/kvm exists
  KVM acceleration can be used
  ```

anybody who know and solve this issues?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The reason of this error is because of the difference of livbirt.
just changed libvirt from 1.2.1 to 1.2.2.
now i can start nova-compute on precise 12.04.

Thanks

Comment: Hi friends, i am getting this error "internal error: Cannot find suitable emulator for x86_64"